# Get All DriveItems from Microsoft Graph SDK C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft Graph SDK for C#. Link is as follows ("https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet").
The query I am using to get all the items from the SharePoint site is as follows.

```
// Get Graph API Token
 GraphServiceClient client = await MicrosoftGraphClient.GetGraphServiceClient();
// Fetch all DriveItems from Sharepoint Site
 var results = await client.Sites[sharePointId].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("SalesPortal/Presentations/" + orgnaization).Children.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

This query is working perfectly fine but it is fetching only the first 200 records. I need all the records present in that path.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/collections.md#getting-a-collection
The results object you have should have a `NextPageRequest` property if there are more results to fetch.
Keep making the NextPageRequest, aggregating your results as your go, until it comes back null.